# Reassign an object on the stack in c++

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory

I'm coming from Java and am finding certain objects very confusing.

In my code I have an Event class that has an attribute of a Cell. When I create a new Event, I want to initialize the cell without using the "new" keyword. The code is below. In the constructor for Event all I can think to do is put "currentCell = new Cell()". Is there some way to initialize currentCell without doing this?

More generally, if I have an object like currentEvent, how can I refresh it to have different information? Say the currentEvent has cell a and time point 10, and now I want it to store cell b and time point 12. In java I would do:

```
Event e1 = new Event(a, 10);
e1 = new Event(b, 12);
```

But I want to do this equivalent thing in c++ without putting anything on the stack.

Here is the event header file:

```
class Event {
public:
    Event();
    int getTime() { return timePoint; }
    void setTime(int newTime); 
    void setCell(Cell & newCell);
    virtual ~Event();
private:
    Cell * currentCell; //Class is made up of a pointer to a cell and a time
    int timePoint;
};
```

And the constructor in Event.cpp:

```
Event::Event()
{
    //Cell currentCell;
    currentCell = new Cell();  //don't want to use new, but do what to initialize currentCell to a blank new cell
    timePoint = rand() % 6 + 5;
}
```

And the general question:

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, CompareEvent> events;
Event firstEvent(*start, time); 
events.push(firstEvent);
Event * newEvent1; //I want to reassign newEvent1 and newEvent2 each time through the loop but would rather not have to use the heap
Event * newEvent2;

//temp int counter
int counter = 0;

while ((!(events.empty())) && (counter<5000)){

    //Get next event
    currentEvent = events.top();
    currentCell = currentEvent.getCell();
    if (currentCell->isAlive()) {

        bool canGrow = false;
        if (currentCell->selfGrows() || currentCell->withinRange()){
            canGrow = true;
        }

        if (canGrow){

            //Perform mitosis

            //Create a daughter cell and add it to the list; increment counter
            daughterCell = new Cell(*currentCell); 

            newEvent1 = new Event(*daughterCell, time, newDir);
            events.push(*newEvent1);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If `currentCell` was *not* a `Cell *` but instead a `Cell`, it would default initialize before your constructor code gets executed. There is also syntax to use constructor parameters.

Comment: You have to be careful because you are using the default copy constructor and default assignment operator for your `Event` class. I recommend implementing them explicitely.

Comment: Some advice -- Since you're coming from Java, you should try to not leverage Java to write C++ code, as doing so will just lead you down the wrong path in solving a problem.  Your code has memory leaks here:  `newEvent1 = new Event(*daughterCell, time, newDir);     events.push(*newEvent1);`  It may look ok in Java, but disastrous in C++.

Comment: @WolfgangZiegler Thanks. I actually do have a copy constructor I was just pasting a minimal set of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I changed this to just be a priority queue of events, rather than pointers, to avoid this leak. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a pointer to a Cell, just have a member Cell. It will be constructed during the construction of the containing Event object.

```
class Event {
public:
    Event();
    int getTime() { return timePoint; }
    void setTime(int newTime); 
    void setCell(Cell & newCell);
    virtual ~Event();
private:
    Cell currentCell; // <-- no need to have this as a pointer (asterisk removed)
    int timePoint;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to initialize the cell without using the "new" keyword.

Initialization is done by the constructor. `new` is used to allocate dynamically (on the heap). These two concepts are orthogonal. So obvisouly, yes, you can do it.

```
newEvent1 = new Event(*daughterCell, time, newDir);
```

If you don't want to create it on the heap, create an object on the stack:

```
Event newEvent1(*daughterCell, time, newDir);
```

Don't forget to create the appropriate construtor which expects these parameters. And check the rule of three.

Comment: Don't forget to cover copying/assignment (it's part of the question).

Comment: I probably won't write more, *seriously*, pick a book or article and learn the basics. Using Java semantics to do C++ programming will lead to disaster...